# Why is my if statement never evaluated?

Tags: c, string, file, loops, pointers

I am making a small program in the C90 standard in GCC Ubuntu 10.04 that searches for a word in a line of text and prints out the line if the word is in that line.

My source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int bytesSearch;
    size_t n = 400;
    char *sentence, *word;
    FILE *pFile;

    pFile = fopen("The War of The Worlds.txt","r");

    if (pFile != NULL) {
        puts ("Please enter a search word:");
        sentence = (char *) malloc (n + 1);
        word = (char *) malloc (n + 1);
        bytesSearch = getline(&word, &n, stdin);
        while ((getline(&sentence, &n, pFile)) != -1) {
            char* strResult = strstr(sentence, word);
            if (strResult) {
                printf("%s\n", sentence);
            }
        }
    }
    free(sentence);
    free(word);
    fclose(pFile);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My issue is my inner if statement never is true, which I'm assuming means there's something wrong with my strstr function call. Can somebody tell me why that if statement never executes and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: This is a good usecase for a debugger. Check your environment which debugger is used and look up how to use it effectively.

Comment: Please provide a minimal set of input files and tell us what you typed into the program so we can reproduce it.

Comment: Try printing `ERRNO` to figure what went wrong.

Comment: Agree with @nvoigt, just set a breakpoint on `fopen` and step through.

Comment: I am curious as to what "sentence" contains on each run.

Comment: Please give your question a better title, that somehow states what your technical problem is, not how you observe it.

Comment: @JensGustedt will do for next time!

Comment: @BenjaminC.Huskisson-Snider, you could just start right now and edit your question, it is never too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) says:

> `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)` reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of
>          the buffer containing the text into `*lineptr`.  The buffer is null-
>          terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.

So you need to remove the `\n` from the end of `word` before you search it in `sentence`.

```
if (pFile != NULL) {
    puts ("Please enter a search word:");
    sentence = (char *) malloc (n + 1);
    word = (char *) malloc (n + 1);
    bytesSearch = getline(&word, &n, stdin);

    if (bytesSearch!=-1) {
        word[strlen(word)-1]='\0'; //removes the '\n' from the word

        while ((getline(&sentence, &n, pFile)) != -1) {
            char* strResult = strstr(sentence, word);
            if (strResult) {
                printf("%s\n", sentence);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        printf("Error taking input!\n");

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Was completely unaware that there was a hidden `\n` at the end of a line.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the string you read from the standard input ends with an unnoticed `\n`.

In this case, searching for a word which is at the end of the line *will* work, whereas searching for a word in the middle of a line will fail, even if it exists.

You might want to remove the trailing newline that is copied into `word`.

One would usually use something such as the following to do this :

```
size_t size = strlen(word);
size_t end = size - 1;
if (size > 0 && word[end] == '\n')
    word[end] = '\0';
```

Comment: A safer alternative is `size_t end = strlen(word); if (end > 0 && word[end-1] == '\n') ...` for the _pedantic_ situations when `strlen(word) == 0`.

Comment: @chux how can `strlen(word) == 0`? The least it could contain is a `\n` character. So that makes `strlen(word) == 1`

Comment: @Rikayan Bandyopadhyay I can think of at least 2 ways: 1) `stdin` is from a re-directed input file that does not end with `\n`. (scratch this as line does not end with \n but is not 0 length) 2) `getline()` reads lines, not C strings and the text being read may contain an embedded `\0` such as "\0anc\n".  3) maybe IO input error. 4) bytesSearch returned -1 and code did not bother to check that as in your answer.  `word` could be anything.

Comment: @chux You are mostly right. However, I was making that point with the sake of readibility in mind ;) Also, your first argument makes no sense. If `stdin` is from a redirected/piped input and does not contain a newline character, the output string will contain the read input, without the newline caracter in it, however. You are correct otherwise.

Comment: @Halim Qarroum I had not complaints about your fine solution, just wanted to add the safer approach for niche cases.  Concerning the redirected input, I added the "(scratch this ...)" as I see it does not result in a `strlen(word)` of 0, but in that case the `word[strlen(word)-1]='\0'` approach of @Rikayan Bandyopadhyay suffers from incorrect truncating the input by a char when it should not - yours does it right. +1

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the '\n' at the end read by getline, you can add this code after reading input,

```
if(word[byteSearch-1]=='\n')
    word[byteSearch-1]='\0';
```